# What is Function Calling Sequence OF Virtual Function In C#?

Tags: c#, .net, function, overriding, virtual

I have this code :

```
namespace ConsoleApplicationDemo
{
    class base 
    {
        public virtual void   Sum()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sum in base ");
        }
    }
    class Program:base 
    {

        public override void Sum()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("SUM  IN Program ");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            base A2 = new Program();
            A2.Sum();
            Program P2 = new Program();
            P2.Sum();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

> getting OutPUT: SUM  IN Program SUM  IN Program

My question  is why base Class Sum FunCtion is not getting called by this code?

```
base A2 = new Program();
A2.Sum();
```

Comment: Because of polymorphism. You'd have to do base A2 = new base() to get the result you're after.

Comment: You can't have a class named `base`. It is a reserved word. Try `Base` or `@base`

Comment: Read [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Better use completely another word instead of base

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have overridden the base classes implementation. [Virtual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)/Override says "Hey every time this method is called use the overridden method."

If you had marked the child class function with the **new** keyword, it would do what you describe. (Personally, I don't like using the **new** keyword, as most people don't understand the nuances of its implementation, but it performs the behavior you described.  There are better alternatives).

[Article describing new keyword.](https://kemiller2002.github.io/2015/03/30/I-thought-you-were-the-new-method.html)

Comment: I don't like your suggestion about `new` because this is reusing an identifier rather than polymorphism...

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I wasn't offering it as a suggestion, I was merely pointing out that new is the action he is describing.  Personally, I don't ever like to use the new keyword for that.

Comment: if it were my own answer, I would completely remove this, because I've seen other Q&As here in SO where a lot of people confuse `new` with polymorphism, but it's up to you!

Comment: The link is not working

Comment: @dodekja should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

A method that is marked a override overwrites the complete implementation of its base-method. So if you create an instance of your derived class `Program`, this overriden method is called. However you may also call the base-implementation from within your derived method by using `base.Sum()`

```
public override void Sum()
{
    base.Sum();  // now you see why base is a really bad name for your class
    Console.WriteLine("SUM  IN Program ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism changes the implementation of your subclass. Even if you upcast a subclass reference to its base type, you won't be able to access base class `virtual` method implementation, but the deepest implementation of the object inheritance.

In the other hand, a derived class can effectively access base class implementation using the `base` keyword:

```
public override void Sum()
{
     // This calls base implementation.
     base.Sum();

     Console.WriteLine("SUM  IN Program ");
}
```

Anyway, `base` will call the immediate base class' implementation. You won't be able to call an implementation above one level in the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword describes what actual type is created, and the variable type `base`  means it can be referenced (used) as at least a `base` type.

Consider a base class `B` and a derived class `A`.

```
public class B { }
public class A: B { }
```

Then `new B()` creates a base class in memory and `new A()` creates a derived class in memory.

You can store the references to these objects in their respective classes or any base class. You can even use `object` to hold a reference since it is the base class for everything in C#.

```
B x1 = new B();
A x2 = new A();
B x3 = new A();
A x4 = new B(); // error: not allowed
object x5 = new B();
object x6 = new A();
```

Specifically, the `.Sum()` function is called on whatever type is initiated in memory with the `new` keyword, regardless of the holding variable type.

<sub>PS. Using `base` as a name is bad idea because it is a C# keyword.</sub>